# wechat upload thumb media file issue

Tags: image, upload, media, wechat

I am currently writing the node application using wechat admin platform api. However i am currently stuck when i try to upload the thumb media image file to the tencent server using admin platform api. I have a subscriber account registered with wechat and i am able to get the access token and follower list of my wechat account successfully using admin api platform.
Following is the wechat code i am using to upload to the wechat server :

```
function uploadThumb(){

console.log('Inside uploadThumb');

var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

    resolve({
        then:function(onfullfill,onreject){
             fs.readdir(thumb_dir,function(err,files){
             if (err){
                onreject();
                throw err;
            }
            files.forEach(function(file){
                 fs.stat(thumb_dir+file, function(err, stats) {
                       var type = "thumb";
                       var upload_url = "http://file.api.wechat.com/cgi-bin/media/upload?access_token="+access_token+"&type="+type;
                     console.log('file name :'+file+': size :'+stats.size);
            restler.post(upload_url, {
                          multipart: true,
                          data: {
                                   "media['filename']": file,
                                   "media['content type']":"image/png",
                                   "media['file length']": stats.size,
                                   "media['file']": restler.file(thumb_dir+file, null, stats.size, null, "image/png")
                                }
                        }).on("complete", function(fdata,response) {
                              console.log('Status: ' + response.statusCode);
                              console.log('Thumb image data :'+fdata);
                              console.dir(response);
                             //var obj = JSON.parse(fdata);
                         //saveUploadMediaToDB(obj,file).then(onfullfill());
                            onfullfill();
                             });
                          });
                      });
                  });               
               }
          });
      });
      return promise;
   }
```

When i run the above function in node , i get the HTTP response code as 502. And text/html response below :

```
    Status: 502
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>???</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  .dn{display:none;}
  .db{display:block;}
  .dib{display:inline-block;}
  .b_dib{display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1;}
  .di{display:inline;}
  .vh{visibility:hidden;}
  .vv{visibility:visible;}
  .rel{position:relative;}
  .abs{position:absolute;}
  .oh{overflow:hidden;}
  .z{*zoom:1;}
  .l{float:left;}
  .r{float:right;}
  .cl{clear:both;}
  .group{*zoom:1;}
  .group:after{content:"\200B";display:block;height:0;clear:both;}
  .tc{text-align:center;}
  .tr{text-align:right;}
  .tl{text-align:left;}
  .tj{text-align:justify;*text-justify:distribute;}
  .vt{vertical-align:top;}
  .vm{vertical-align:middle;}
  .vb{vertical-align:bottom;}
  .f0{font-size:0;}
  .fa{font-family:Arial;}
  .fs{font-family:SimSun;}
  .fyh{font-family:"Microsoft YaHei";}
  .indent{text-indent:2em;}
  .n{font-weight:400;font-style:normal;}
  .b{font-weight:700;}
  .i{font-style:italic;}
  .tdn{text-decoration:none;}
  .tdn:hover{text-decoration:none;}
  .poi{cursor:pointer;}
  .text-hide{line-height:999em;overflow:hidden;}
  .drop_hl_extra{padding-left:999em;margin-left:-999em;}
  .drop_vb_extra{padding-bottom:999em;margin-bottom:-999em;}
  html{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;}
  body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,p,ul,ol,dl,dd{margin:0;}
  ul,ol{padding-left:0;list-style-type:none;}
  a img{border:0;}
  body{background-color:#EAEAEA;font-family:"Microsoft YaHei",Helvetica,Verdana,Arial,Tahoma;font-size:14px;color:#222222;}
  .logo{padding-top:25px;}
  .wrapper{width:960px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
  .container{margin-top:20px;box-shadow:0 3px 3px #ddd;-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 3px #ddd;-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 3px #ddd;border-radius:3px;-moz-border-rad
  .err_wrapper{overflow:hidden;*zoom:1;padding:100px 260px 100px 260px;}
  .err_icon_holder{float:left;}
  .err_content{margin-left:180px;margin-top:30px;}
  .err_t{font-weight:700;font-size:20px;line-height:30px;}
  .err_text{line-height:28px;}
  .footer{padding-top:40px;font-size:12px;color:#999999;text-shadow:0 1px 1px #ffffff;text-align:center;}
  .page_link a{color:#4d5d2c;text-decoration:none;}
  .err_icon{display:inline-block;width:170px;height:130px;background:transparent url("http://res.wx.qq.com/mpres/htmledition/images/icon_page_err.png") n

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1 class="logo"><a href="http://mp.weixin.qq.com"><img src="http://res.wx.qq.com/mpres/htmledition/images/login/logo.png" alt="??????"></a></h1>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="err_wrapper">
          <span class="err_icon_holder"><i class="err_icon page_503"></i></span>
          <div class="err_content">
            <h3 class="err_t">503 : HTTP Error 503</h3>
            <p class="err_text">???????,????????</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p class="page_link">
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.tencent.com/zh-cn/index.shtml">????</a>
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a target="_blank" href="http://mp.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/readtemplate?t=wxm-agreement&amp;type=info&amp;lang=zh_CN">????</a>
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a target="_blank" href="http://kf.qq.com/special_auto/weixin.html">????</a>
      </p>
      <p class="copyright">
        Copyright&nbsp;c 2012-2013 Tencent. All Rights Reserved.
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Please help me by pointing in correct direction , whether this approach is correct or am i doing something basically wronge.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I've been able to find in the Restler documentation, and comparing it with the WeChat API documentation, it seems like you might be specifying the incorrect request parameter.

I think you might need to replace

```
restler.post(upload_url, {
  multipart: true,
  data: {
    "media['filename']": file,
    "media['content type']":"image/png",
    "media['file length']": stats.size,
    "media['file']": restler.file(thumb_dir+file, null, stats.size, null, "image/png")
  }
[...]
```

With something along these lines:

```
restler.post(upload_url, {
  multipart: true,
  data: {
    "media": restler.file(thumb_dir+file, null, stats.size, null, "image/png")
  }
[...]
```